# Basic SQL query

Tags: sql

I've got a question for my uni exam, I would appreciate if anyone could have a look at it.

List all the details of the longest film being shown in a performance sponsored
by Joe’s Diner.

Tables:

```
Sponsor (sid, sname, business type)
Film (director, title, length)
Cinema (cname, address, seating capacity)
Performance (director, title, cname, pdate, price, sid)
```

My answer is:

```
SELECT f.director, f.title, max(f.length)
FROM (film f 
      JOIN performance p ON f.director=p.director AND f.title=p.title
     ) 
JOIN sponsor s USING sid
WHERE sname='Joe’s Diner'
GROUP BY f.director, f.title;
```

Comment: OK, what is your question?

Comment: What is the target DBMS?

Comment: Do you guys think it's correct?

Comment: @LaszloMoricz:- Execute the query and check if you get what you want. If not then do provide us more details.

Comment: The `using` syntax can be iffy depending on DBMS.  also you may run into a reserved word error on `length`; and might have to escape it (again depending on DBMS)... You run a minor risk with a problem with this query if SID were to be inserted into Film or Cinema at some point in the future.  However, it will may not return a single record.  It will return the director, title and length of all movies sponsored by Joe's Diner.  If you want ONLY the max this query will not work.  It also doesn't return "All detailsas requested.

Comment: This will return all of the movies sponsored by `Joe's Diner` as well as it's max(length) which is probably the same as it's length. In fact, this would probably return the same results if you removed the Max and and added length to the group by. So, no. Not quite right. Instead you should focus on first finding the film with the max(length) sponsered by `Joe's cathouse` then worry about finding all of that films details. A subquery will be needed for sure.

Comment: You might be able to use `over` syntax instead of a subquery (Depending on dbms)

Comment: I think it is wrong.  You should see it is wrong if you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all the details of the longest film being shown in a performance sponsored by Joe’s Diner.

Tables:

```
Sponsor (sid, sname, business type)
Film (director, title, length)
Cinema (cname, address, seating capacity)
Performance (director, title, cname, pdate, price, sid)
```

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Film --top 1 and order by get longest
INNER JOIN Performance --you have to join performance so you can join sponsor
    ON Film.director = Performance.director
    AND Film.title = Performance.title
INNER JOIN Sponsor --so you can limit to Joe's
    ON Performance.sid = Sponsor.sid
WHERE Sponsor.sname = 'Joe''s Diner'  --to get only this guy
ORDER BY Film.length DESC  --to get longest with top 1
```

Not tested.